# How to save none nullable dataframe to a hive table?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a dataframe in spark which has a non nullable column in it. When I save it to HIVE and then read it from HIVE the non nullable column is nullable. What might be wrong?

For some context I am taking an existing dataframe and changing it's schema to include that none nullable property.

```
df = spark.table("myhive_table")
df.printSchema()
=> root
   |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
   |-- col2: string (nullable = true)

schema = StructType([StructField("col1",spark_types.StringType(), True),
                    StructField("col2",spark_types.DoubleType(), False),
                    ])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd,schema)
df2.printSchema()
=> root
   |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
   |-- col2: string (nullable = false)

spark.sql('drop table myhive_table')
df.write.saveAsTable("myhive_table",overwrite = True)

spark.table("myhive_table").printSchema()
=> root
   |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
   |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-16575

Comment: Thanks for the link!